# How to run mongoose query in cron job?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cron

```
try {        
  var cronDo = new CronJob({
    cronTime: '* * * * * *',
    onTick: function () {
      user.find({}, function (err, doc) {
        console.log("--------------testing-----------");
      });              
    },
    start: false,
    timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
  });

  cronDo.start();
} catch (ex) {
  console.log("cron pattern not valid");
}
```

What is wrong in my code? I am not getting any output. While if I remove mongo's part then cron is giving output.

Comment: mongoodb find callback is async. So I guess what is happening is your cron is getting executed and then the async find function callback is getting the result to log in console.

Comment: Thanks, I got the clue.
I solved by requiring mongodb configuration in the cron file.